# Moving columns within a data.frame() without retyping

Tags: r

Is there a method for moving a column from one position in a data.frame to the next - without typing an entirely new data.frame()

For example:

```
a <- b <- c <- d <- e <- f <- g <- 1:100
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
```

Now let's say I wanted "g" in front of "a"

I could retype it, as

```
df <- data.frame(g,a,b,c,d,e,f)
```

But is there not a quicker way? (Imagine 1500+ columns)

Comment: `append` function can be helpful...

Comment: @aL3xa, I recently wrote [a function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18540144/1270695) that takes the `append` approach.

Comment: An easy `data.table` alternative: [R data.table compute new column, but insert at beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754756/r-data-table-compute-new-column-but-insert-at-beginning)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
> col_idx <- grep("g", names(df))
> df <- df[, c(col_idx, (1:ncol(df))[-col_idx])]
> names(df)
[1] "g" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
```

Comment: I think this is the same basic idea: `df[,c("g",setdiff(names(df),"g"))]`

Comment: How could I use this to move "G" to any position I wanted? Perhaps I wanted "G" to be the 2nd column or the 4th?

Comment: @david probably be easier using Ken's solution. Something like `subset(df, select=c(a:b,g,c:f))`

Answer (score 78):

The `subset` function has a nice `select` argument that gives a convenient way to select ranges of columns by name:

```
df <- subset(df, select=c(g,a:f))
```

Comment: Note: this also works with numbers instead of colnames

Comment: not applicable to hundreds of columns, with real names

Comment: @Ferroao - it doesn't matter whether it's real names or these fake ones `a:g`, it works just as well if you do `subset(df, select=c(foo, bar:baz))`.  In particular it doesn't depend on the names being ordered, if that's what you're concerned about.

Answer (score 65):

I wrote this function recently called `moveme`. It's designed to work on vectors, with the intent of shuffling column orders around.

Here's the function:

```
moveme <- function (invec, movecommand) {
  movecommand <- lapply(strsplit(strsplit(movecommand, ";")[[1]], 
                                 ",|\\s+"), function(x) x[x != ""])
  movelist <- lapply(movecommand, function(x) {
    Where <- x[which(x %in% c("before", "after", "first", 
                              "last")):length(x)]
    ToMove <- setdiff(x, Where)
    list(ToMove, Where)
  })
  myVec <- invec
  for (i in seq_along(movelist)) {
    temp <- setdiff(myVec, movelist[[i]][[1]])
    A <- movelist[[i]][[2]][1]
    if (A %in% c("before", "after")) {
      ba <- movelist[[i]][[2]][2]
      if (A == "before") {
        after <- match(ba, temp) - 1
      }
      else if (A == "after") {
        after <- match(ba, temp)
      }
    }
    else if (A == "first") {
      after <- 0
    }
    else if (A == "last") {
      after <- length(myVec)
    }
    myVec <- append(temp, values = movelist[[i]][[1]], after = after)
  }
  myVec
}
```

Usage is simple. Try these out:

```
moveme(names(df), "g first")
moveme(names(df), "g first; a last; e before c")
```

Of course, using it to reorder the columns in your `data.frame` is straightforward:

```
df[moveme(names(df), "g first")]
```

And for `data.table`s (moves by reference, no copy) :

```
setcolorder(dt, moveme(names(dt), "g first"))
```

---

The basic options are:

- first
- last
- before
- after

Compounded moves are separated by a semicolon.

Comment: this function is really useful! Why not include it in data.table?

Comment: @WetFeet, thanks! I enjoyed writing the Function. Not sure if Matthew Dowle sees an actual need for it though :-)

Comment: excellent, that's going in my .Rprofile. +1 for adding to data.table. Stata has a similar capabality

Comment: it would be interesting to make it work when column names have spaces "column name"

Comment: @Ferroao That would be a good modification. Not sure just yet how to implement it reliably.

Comment: maybe the user can put \`col name\`

Comment: I use this function all the time.  Massively helpful. +1

Comment: it is very slow on data frames of many rows though. Nearly 28 seconds on a data frame of 8 columns, 1.6 milion rows

Comment: @Mark, sorry--cannot reproduce, and there's no reason that it should depend on the size of the `data.frame` -- only on the number of moves required. Perhaps you're mixing up the time it takes to *print* a large `data.frame` to the console rather than the amount of time it takes to reorder the columns. For instance, if you have a `data.frame` named "DF" and did `system.time(DF[moveme(names(DF), "V8 before V5; V3 last")])` that should take no time, but `system.time(print(DF[moveme(names(DF), "V8 before V5; V3 last")]))` would definitely rack up at least a few seconds (7 seconds on my system).

Answer (score 61):

Use `select` from the [dplyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf) package and its `everything()` function to move specific columns to the start or end of a data.frame.

**Move to the beginning:**

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  select(g, everything())
```

**Move to the end:**

```
df %>%
  select(-a, everything())
```

Or without the `%>%` pipe operator, those would be `select(df, g, everything())` and `select(df, -a, everything())` respectively.

Comment: `df %>% select(-a, a)` also works to move column `a` to the end

Comment: Does it offer the option to move to nth place? Ty.

Answer (score 14):

Here is my solution

```
df[c(7,1:6)]
```

or you can also reorder by column name:

```
df[c("g",names(df)[-7])]
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `relocate` from `dplyr` package

```
mtcars %>% 
   # dplyr::relocate(disp) %>% ## simply make disp the first column
   relocate(starts_with("c"), .after = disp)  %>% ## more complex column order shuffling
   head(3)
```

Note, that the function was added with version 1.0, see https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/dplyr-1-0-0-select-rename-relocate/

Answer (score 4):

This is a very old post , but I developed this code which dynamically changes column position within a dataframe. Just change the value of n and Column Name ("g" here) and get dataframe with new column arrangements.

```
df1 = subset(df, select = c(head(names(df),n=3),"g", names(df) [! names(df) %in% c(head(names(df),n=3),"g")]))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is slightly more elegant and allows to arrange first few leftmost columns and leave the rest unarranged to the right.

```
ordered_columns_leftside=c('var10','var34','var8')
df=df[c(ordered_columns_leftside, setdiff(names(df),ordered_columns_leftside))]
```

Comment: Of all the many alternatives provided to move columns without having to name all columns (and thus useful for moving only the last column in a dataframe with doznes of colums) this is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar way I used to move 'n'th column to 2nd position in a huge data frame based on the column name.

**Move a column to first position:**

```
## Move a column with name "col_name"  to first column 
colX <- grep("^col_name", colnames(df.original)) 
# get the column position from name 

df.reordered.1 <- df.original[,c(colX,1:(colX-1), (colX+1):length(df.original))]  
# get new reordered data.frame
# if the column is the last one, error "undefined columns selected" will show up. Then do the following command instead of this

df.reordered.1 <- df.original[,c(colX,1:(colX-1)]  
# get new reordered data.frame, if the column is the last one
```

**From anywhere to To 'n'th position**

```
## Move a column with name "col_name"  to column position "n", 
## where n > 1 (in a data.frame "df.original")

colX <- grep("^col_name", colnames(df.original)) 
# get the column position from name 

n <- 2 
# give the new expected column position (change to the position you need) 

df.reordered.2 <- df.original[,c(1:(n-1), colX, n:(colX-1), (colX+1):length(df.original))] 
# get new reordered data.frame

## Optional; to replace the original data frame with sorted data.frame 
## if the sorting looks good
df.original <- df.reordered.2
rm(df.reordered.2) # remove df
```

Comment: not working from several possibilities, example, colname= b n=5

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple but flexible function I wrote to move a column anywhere in a data frame.

```
move.col <- function(df, move_this, next_to_this, before = FALSE) {
  if (before==FALSE)
    df[,c(match(setdiff(names(df)[1:which(names(df)==next_to_this)],move_this),names(df)),
          match(move_this,names(df)),
          match(setdiff(names(df)[which(names(df)==next_to_this):ncol(df)],c(next_to_this,move_this)),names(df)))]
  else
    df[,c(match(setdiff(names(df)[1:(which(names(df)==next_to_this))],c(next_to_this,move_this)),names(df)),
          match(move_this,names(df)),
          match(setdiff(names(df)[(which(names(df)==next_to_this)):ncol(df)],move_this),names(df)))]
}
```

**Usage:**
Specify the data frame (`df`), the column name you want to move (`move_this`), and the column name of which you want to move beside (`next_to_this`). By default, the function will move the `move_this` column *after* the `next_to_this` column. You can specify `before = TRUE` to move `move_this` before `next_to_this`.

**Examples:**

1. Move "b" after "g" (i.e., make "b" last column).

`move.col(df, "b", "g")`

2. Move "c" after "e".

`move.col(df, "c", "e")`

3. Move "g" before "a" (i.e., make "g" first column).

`move.col(df, "g", "a", before=TRUE)`

4. Move "d" and "f" before "b" (i.e., move multiple columns).

`move.col(df,c("d","f"),"b", before=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

Most solutions seem overly verbose or lack encapsulation. Here's another way to solve the problem

```
push_left <- function(df, pushColNames){
    df[, c(pushColNames, setdiff(names(df), pushColNames))]
}

push_left(iris, c("Species", "Sepal.Length"))
```

Comment: This one gets my vote because it will maintain labels

Answer (score 1):

I found a pretty simple way of doing this that suited my needs and doesn't take much time.

You have the following column names: "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"

Move "d" to second position (after "a"):

```
attach(df)

df <- cbind(a, d, df[,c(2:3,5:10)])
```

Move "j" to 4th position (after "c"):

```
df <- cbind(df[,c(1:3)], j, df[,c(4:9)])
```

Answer (score 1):

For `data.table` users :

Use `setcolorder()`.

```
setDT(df) # convert into data.table

setcolorder(df,'g') # column g comes first if not all column names are mentioned
setcolorder(df, 7)  # same as above

df

       g   a   b   c   d   e   f
  1:   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
  2:   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
  3:   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
  4:   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
  5:   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
  6:   6   6   6   6   6   6   6
  7:   7   7   7   7   7   7   7
```

In case when column 'a' and 'b' should be moved to rightmost:

```
setcolorder(df,3:7) 
df

       c   d   e   f   g   a   b
  1:   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
  2:   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
  3:   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
  4:   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
  5:   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
  6:   6   6   6   6   6   6   6
  7:   7   7   7   7   7   7   7
```

Answer (score 0):

If the reordering is a shift, as in your example, you can use the `shift` function from the `taRifx` package. It acts on vectors, hence apply it to the column names:

```
> a <- b <- c <- d <- e <- f <- g <- 1:5
> df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
> df[, taRifx::shift(seq_along(df),-1)]
  g a b c d e f
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

In fact the `shift` function can also be applied to a data frame, but not as expected. You can write a function:

```
> shift_df <- function(df, n) df[, taRifx::shift(seq_along(df),n)]
> shift_df(df, -1)
  g a b c d e f
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
> shift_df(df, 2)
  c d e f g a b
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to contribute another universal working approach, similar to the previous answers of rcs, Manuel and Scott Kaiser, which only work in specific cases:

```
move<-function(new.pos,nameofcolumn,dfname) {
  col_idx <- grep(nameofcolumn, names(dfname))
  if (length(col_idx)==0){print("invalid column name");return(dfname)} else {
  if(new.pos>ncol(dfname)){print("invalid column number");return(dfname)} else {
  if (new.pos==1) {
    b<-dfname[ , c( col_idx, c((new.pos):ncol(dfname))[-(abs(new.pos-1-col_idx))] )]  
    }
  else if(col_idx==1 & new.pos==ncol(dfname)){
    b<-dfname[ , c((1:(new.pos-1)+1), col_idx )] 
    }
  else if(col_idx==1){
    b<-dfname[ , c((1:(new.pos-1)+1), col_idx, c((new.pos+1):ncol(dfname)) )] 
    }
  else if(new.pos==ncol(dfname)){
    b<-dfname[ , c((1:(new.pos))[-col_idx], col_idx)] 
    }
  else if(new.pos>col_idx){
    b<-dfname[ , c((1:(new.pos))[-col_idx], col_idx, c((new.pos+1):ncol(dfname)) )] 
    } 
  else{
    b<-dfname[ , c((1:(new.pos-1)), col_idx, c((new.pos):ncol(dfname))[-(abs(new.pos-1-col_idx))] )]
    }
  return(b)
  if(length(ncol(b))!=length(ncol(dfname))){print("error")}
  }
}}
```

Usage:

```
a <- b <- c <- d <- e <- f <- g <- 1:5
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
move(1,"g",df)
```

Comment: The `<<-` is unnecessary. Indentation and more spaces would make your code much more readable.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one function that might help

- *df*: the dataframe
- *ColName*: the name of the column(s) to be moved
- *Position*: the column number that you want the moved column to appear

---

```
moveCol <- function(df,ColName,Position=1) {
    D <- dim(df)[2]
    DFnames <- names(df)
    if (Position>D+1 | Position<1) {
        warning(paste0('Column position ',sprintf('%d',Position), ' is out of range [1-',sprintf('%d',D),']'))
        return()
    }
    for (i in ColName) {
        x <- i==DFnames
        if (all(!x)) {
            warning(paste0('Column \"', i, '\" not found'))
        } else {
            D1 <- seq(D)
            D1[x] = Position - 0.5
            df<- df[order(D1)]
        }
    }
    return(df)
}
```

Comment: in several cases, +1 has to be added to "Position" to work as expected

Answer (score -2):

@David asked how to move "G" to an arbitrary position, such as 4. Building on @rcs answer,

```
new.pos <- 4
col_idx <- grep("g", names(df))
df      <- df[ , c((1:new.pos)[-col_idx], col_idx, c((new.pos):ncol(df))[-col_idx])]
```

Comment: Doesn't work... try with `df = mtcars` moving the `"cyl"` column to position 4: You get two copies of the `hp` column and the `drat` column is dropped.

Comment: I think you can make it work if instead of using `[-col_idx]` you use `setdiff(1:new.pos, col_idx)` (and similarly for the other end of the sequence). You also need the tail of the sequence to start at `new.pos + 1` otherwise the column originally at `new.pos` is duplicated.