# How to move last colum to the front in R

Tags: r

am pretty new to R.Have a data frame and need to relocate the last variable to the front but i can not figure out how to achieve this. Can somebody tell me quite easy but understandable how i can move the column newVariable to the front? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWlVV.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move a column to first position in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286419/move-a-column-to-first-position-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 1):

Reorder the columns

```
n = ncol(datensatz11)
new.order = c(n, 1:(n-1))
datensatz11 = datensatz11[, new.order]
```