# Placing transformed variables near their "parent" variables

Tags: r, tidyverse

When I create transformed variables in a dataframe (e.g., standardized versions of existing variables), it would often be convenient if they were placed alongside their "parent" variables in this manner (e.g., varname1, varname1_z, varname2, varname2_z, etc.). But the default placement of new variables is at the end of the dataframe.

Is there a way to efficiently place newly created variables alongside their "parent" variable, so as to keep the data better organized?

I can currently change variable positions in the dataframe using select() and a custom function called [moveme()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369959/moving-columns-within-a-data-frame-without-retyping/18540144#18540144), but I am trying to make this variable placement process more automated, so that variables are placed as they are created.

In the code example below you'll see all of my newly created "_z" variables at the end of the dataframe. Is there a way I could place them alongside their unstandardized parent in an automated manner?

Thank you for any support.

```
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(z = scale(.) %>% as.double()))
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but you should think about whether you really want to use wide-formatted data in the tidyverse.  One way to get z-scores for everything right next to the source is to have only two columns: one for the raw variables and one for the z-scores.  Like this: `numeric_cols <- mpg %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% names;

mpg %>%
    group_by_if(not_numeric) %>%
    gather(quantity, value, !! numeric_cols) %>%
    group_by(quantity) %>%
    mutate(z_score = scale(value))`

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful suggestion @Curt F. Maybe I'm hung up, but I think it is often useful (even in the tidyverse) to have variable order reflect the data collection order. Z-scored variables were really just an example. In cleaning a survey dataset I often need to reverse-score variables in order to get to a dataset that is both tidy and ready for analysis.

Comment: I'll post an example of how you can get the arrangement you want by going through multiple rounds of spread and gather.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to:

1. First `gather()` your data into a "long" format, grouping as required
2. Do data transformations (e.g. create z-scores) to add a new column
3. `gather()` again to put new and old data columns in a single column
4. `spread()` the data into a format that you like.

Here's an example:

```
numeric_cols <- mpg %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% names

mpg %>%
    rownames_to_column %>%
    mutate(rowname = rowname %>% as.numeric) %>%
    gather(param, quantity, !! numeric_cols) %>%
    group_by(param) %>%
    mutate(z_score = scale(quantity)) %>%
    gather(number_type, value, quantity:z_score)  %>%
    unite(new_col_name, param, number_type) %>%
    spread(new_col_name, value)
```

This results in a data frame that has a `head()` of

```
  rowname manufacturer model trans      drv fl class   cty_quantity cty_z_score
1 1       audi         a4    auto(l5)   f   p  compact 18            0.2681016 
2 2       audi         a4    manual(m5) f   p  compact 21            0.9729978 
3 3       audi         a4    manual(m6) f   p  compact 20            0.7380324 
4 4       audi         a4    auto(av)   f   p  compact 21            0.9729978 
5 5       audi         a4    auto(l5)   f   p  compact 16           -0.2018293 
6 6       audi         a4    manual(m5) f   p  compact 18            0.2681016 
  cyl_quantity cyl_z_score displ_quantity displ_z_score hwy_quantity
1 4            -1.1721058  1.8            -1.2939999    29          
2 4            -1.1721058  1.8            -1.2939999    29          
3 4            -1.1721058  2.0            -1.1391962    31          
4 4            -1.1721058  2.0            -1.1391962    30          
5 6             0.0689474  2.8            -0.5199816    26          
6 6             0.0689474  2.8            -0.5199816    26          
  hwy_z_score year_quantity year_z_score
1 0.9336964   1999          -0.997861   
2 0.9336964   1999          -0.997861   
3 1.2695687   2008           0.997861   
4 1.1016326   2008           0.997861   
5 0.4298879   1999          -0.997861   
6 0.4298879   1999          -0.997861
```

I think that has the form you want.  A couple of notes:

- The `group_by` is necessary so that z-scores are created for each parameter, instead of calculating a nonsense z-score over all numbers in the dataset
- The columns are arranged this way because we did `unite(..., param, number_type)` instead of `unite(..., number_type, param)`.  The latter would have grouped all untransformed columns together, followed by all z-score columns.
- The `rownames_to_column` line is required because otherwise the rows of the starting dataframe are not unique, which gives `spread()` problems when trying to figure out how to re-form the wide data.

Comment: That is some impressive data wrangling @ Curt F. Do you have any suggestions about performing these tactics when you only to transform some of the variables? I often need to reverse code about 1/3 of my variables because of their valence.