# R data.table compute new column, but insert at beginning

Tags: r, data.table

In R `data.table`s, I can use this syntax to add a new column:

```
> dt <- data.table(a=c(1,2), b=c(3,4))
> dt[, c := a + b]
> dt
   a b c
1: 1 3 4
2: 2 4 6
```

But how would I insert c at the front of the dt like so:

```
   c a b
1: 4 1 3
2: 6 2 4
```

I looked on SO, and found some people suggesting `cbind` for `data.frame`s, but it's more convenient for me to use the `:=` syntax here, so I was wondering if there was a `data.table` sanctioned way of doing this. My `data.table` has around 100 columns, so I don't want to list them all out.

Answer (score 12):

> Update: This feature has now been merged into the latest CRAN version of `data.table` (starting with v1.11.0), so installing the development version is no longer necessary to use this feature. From the release notes:
>
> 6. setcolorder() now accepts less than ncol(DT) columns to be moved to the front, #592. Thanks @MichaelChirico for the PR.

Current development version of `data.table` (v1.10.5) has updates to `setcolorder()` that make this way more convenient by accepting a partial list of columns. The columns provided are placed first, and then all non-specified columns are added after in the existing order.

[Installation instructions for development branch here.](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

*Note regarding development branch stability: I've been running it for several months now to utilize the multi-threaded version in `fread()` in v1.10.5 (that alone is worth the update if you deal with multi-GB .csv files) and I have not noticed any bugs or regressions for my usage.*

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(mtcars)
DT[1:5]
```

gives

```
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

re-order columns based on a partial list:

```
setcolorder(DT,c("gear","carb"))
DT[1:5]
```

now gives

```
   gear carb  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am
1:    4    4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1
2:    4    4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1
3:    4    1 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1
4:    3    1 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0
5:    3    2 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0
```

---

If for any reason you don't want to update to the development branch, the following works in previous (and current CRAN) versions.

```
newCols <- c("gear","carb")
setcolorder(DT,c(newCols, setdiff(newCols,colnames(DT)) ## (Per Frank's advice in comments)

## the long way I'd always done before seeing setdiff()
## setcolorder(DT,c(newCols,colnames(DT)[which(!colnames(DT) %in% newCols)]))
```

Comment: Fyi, `x[which(!x %in% y)]` is the same as `setdiff(x, y)` assuming `x` has no duplicated values.

Comment: @Frank I've never actually used `setdiff()` or  `intersect()`, those are great convenience functions I didn't know existed. Thanks for the pointer, this is going to save me a lot of keystrokes in the future!